# Counter() is triple counting items in nested list

Tags: python, nested, nltk, counter

I want to search [a text file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vf8j94GNobOcdsg0lgUbMM7i55CPpLTq) for specific keywords, then create a dictionary with the absolute counts and relative frequency of each keyword. I'm using Counter() within a nested loop that should look up each keyword in my list and then count how often each appears in the document. But, while Counter correctly counts each keyword, it then multiplies this count by the total number of keywords. I think I am setting up my nested loop incorrectly.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import FreqDist
import io
from collections import Counter


with io.open('copy.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') as tempFile:
    rawText =  tempFile.read()
    rawText = rawText.lower()

cnt = Counter()

tokens = word_tokenize(rawText)

keywords = ['kingdom', 'phylum', 'class', 'status']

for keyword in keywords:
    for keyword in tokens:
        cnt[keyword] += 1

for keyword in keywords:
    d = {'Keyword': keyword, 'Count': cnt[keyword], 'Frequency':cnt[keyword]/float(len(tokens))}
    print(d)
```

I should see:

```
{'Count': 2, 'Frequency': 0.000882223202470225, 'Keyword': 'kingdom'}
{'Count': 6, 'Frequency': 0.002646669607410675, 'Keyword': 'phylum'}
{'Count': 14, 'Frequency': 0.0061755624172915745, 'Keyword': 'class'}
{'Count': 2, 'Frequency': 0.000882223202470225, 'Keyword': 'status'}
```

But instead I see:

```
{'Count': 8, 'Frequency': 0.000882223202470225, 'Keyword': 'kingdom'}
{'Count': 24, 'Frequency': 0.002646669607410675, 'Keyword': 'phylum'}
{'Count': 56, 'Frequency': 0.0061755624172915745, 'Keyword': 'class'}
{'Count': 8, 'Frequency': 0.000882223202470225, 'Keyword': 'status'}
```

Comment: The first outer "for keyword in keywords:" loop doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had the order of my for loops reversed. This seems to work:

```
for token in tokens:
    if token in keywords:
        cnt[token] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
for keyword in keywords:
    for keyword in tokens:
        cnt[keyword] += 1
```

You are counting again and again for the length of your keyword.

If you can post your `rawtext`, I may able to provide complete solution.

Comment: I uploaded the file I'm analyzing (just a sample copy/pasted from wikipedia). Thanks for your help.